# why the on start activity - the focus is on my EditText and i can't remove it?

Tags: android

I have few ui component on my application ( button, EditText , ListView ).
When i start my application the focus is always on the EditText as default ( even if i didn't focus on this EditText control ) - and the cursor is blinking on this EditText control.

i can use 'setCursorVisible' method - but i don't see any reason to do it.

How i make this EditText to be focus only on click on this controler ?

I try to define 'android:focusableInTouchMode="true"'  but this is not help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `android:focusable="true"` & `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to a parent element (`LinearLayout`/`RelativeLayout`/`FrameLayout`/..) of your layout. Because the first focusable element in hierarchy gains the focus the parent element will take it and it should resolve your problem.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/companyInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/company"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_company"
                android:inputType="text"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```